# Kibana 4 - How to display datapoints on split lines chart which are above value only

Tags: kibana-4

I'm monitoring log data from distributed build system. Each source file has its compile time.

I'm plotting data using average of compilation duration on Y axis and date histogram with @timestamp on X axis. I added Split Lines with Top 10 terms sub aggregation to observe if building of files is shorter or longer in time.

**The problem is that I would like to show only data points which are above certain threshold value.** I tried to cut plot on Y axis but this caused some lines went off screen connecting to data points which was cut off.

Comment: What if you coupled that with querying for only the values that are above that threshold?

Comment: @AlainCollins can you show me the example of such query and where to input it?